# What are the criteria for .d.ts files to be loaded(/when are they loaded) and from what directories?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript, typescript-definitions

Still relative new to Typescript itself and I've been breaking my head on when `.d.ts` files get loaded.

For now I've been putting everything in the `src` directory with everything else, but that feels counter intuitive.

I've peered over all the TS documentation and there doesn't seem to be a conclusive answer.

I've also found the `types` option for `package.json`.

Before I dive into the sources, can someone explain this to me?

Are `.d.ts` parsed anywhere in the path? Just under the `baseUrl` option in `tsconfig.json` or `types` directories specified in the `package.json`? And what is the priority/order in which those directories/paths get evaluated?

Example:

In a React project, I am trying to use a custom `globals.d.ts` file from a sub-directory of `src`, but it is never picked up.

Comment: Put your declaration file anywhere within the project folder, and it should be picked up at compile time

Comment: @smac89 "_In a React project, I am trying to use a custom globals.d.ts file from a sub-directory of src, but it is never picked up._"

Comment: _"it is never picked up"_... what exactly does this mean? How are you verifying that?

Comment: 1) I agree with the above comment. a [mre] would be very helpful here. 2) can you check if there's anything about your tsconfig.json's `"files"`, `"include"`, or `"exclude"` properties that could be preventing your globals.d.ts files from being treated as part of the project? I'm pretty sure both the globals.d.ts file and the file that wants to use its declarations must be part of the project.